# getting started with geth and ENS commands: Error: invalid address

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ens

I'm starting from square zero, sorry. I'm just trying to get a javascript console up and running so that I can learn more about ENS:

http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/userguide.html#resolving

I've spun up an Ubuntu 16.04.2 VM and installed geth, so in one window I just fire it up.

Then in another window I'm just trying to preload **ensutils.js** so I can resolve a few ENS names.

I try this:

```
$ geth --preload "/home/phb/ens/ensutils.js" attach
```

and this happens:

```
Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: /home/phb/ens/ensutils.js: Error: invalid address
at web3.js:3879:15
at web3.js:3683:22
at web3.js:4948:28
at map (<native code>)
at web3.js:4947:12
at web3.js:4973:18
at web3.js:4998:23
at web3.js:4026:22
at apply (<native code>)
at web3.js:4151:12
```

Now I have no idea what to do with that. I'm hoping to get to the point where I have a geth console and I can try things like:

```
ens.resolver(namehash('somename.eth'));
```

If I can just get the extremly newbie basics of how to get that far I, it'll help. Thx in advance.

Comment: I am suspecting this is the direction I'm supposed to go:

`web3.eth.defaultAccount = eth.accounts[0]`

but I'm still getting an Invalid address

Comment: At the geth console what is the value returned by `eth.getBlock('latest').number`? "Invalid address" in ensutils.js is often the result of an unsynch'd blockchain.

Comment: instead of web3.eth.accounts[0] use the getAccounts function (with callback or simply);
let accounts = web3.eth.getAccounts();
web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0];

Answer (score 0):

A common reason for this error is that the blockchain that you are querying has not synchronized. Confirm with `web3.eth.syncing`.